# Exclude Base Image from More Views using PHP (Not with Exclude Box)

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a Magento issue where the image selected as the base image is shown twice, once as the main image and once as a "more views" image. The problem is that the base image hasn't been checked as "Exclude" on all the thousands and thousands of products.

Is there a Magento way to either pull the full gallery of images, regardless of if "Exclude" is checked or not, or to pull all the images except the one selected as "base image".

**Current Code**

```
<a href="<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel());?>" />
   <img src="<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel());?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel());?>" />
</a>
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 1): ?>
   <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($additionalImageSize[0], $additionalImageSize[1]); ?>" class="swipebox"  title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel());?>" />
              <img data-src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($additionalImageSize[0], $additionalImageSize[1]); ?>" alt="<?php echo $subtitle; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel());?>"/>
        </a>
   <?php endforeach; ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Currently it pulls the main image, and then it pulls the gallery. I'm trying to just pull the ENTIRE gallery regardless of "Exclude", or pull the gallery except the base image.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been found

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if ($_product->getImage() == $_image->getFile())
     continue;
?>
```

Added this directly after the foreach statement, now it pulls all images except the first one.